# How to add icon on payment method?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, image, phtml

I want to add icon to payment method to be like this http://prntscr.com/hvj56n

this is the code from `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml`

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give some easy way:

1. Go to `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml` if you haven't it in your theme, copy it from the `{your package}/default` or `base/default`
2. add this: `<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/'.$_code.'.jpg') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?>" />` after `p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>`

So you'll have something like this:

```
<label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/'.$_code.'.png') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?>" /> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
```

3. Add your icon payment in `skin/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/images/paymentcode.png`
4. clear your Magento and browser cache.

Comment: this is good. but I think this if I want to add to 1 method, I want to add 3 icons to different 3 methods?

thank you brother for the help[

Comment: No, please read carrefully my answer, here we get the name of icon method dynamically with `$_code` method. in server you have to put the same name code method to your icon and you'll have all the available methods.

Comment: sorry, brother I still not got it, how would be the code if I want to add 3 icons?

Comment: Did you do exactlly what i told you ? try it an you'll find them, the code is the same for the all methods, if you take a look on `methods.phtml` you will find a `foreach ($methods as $_method):` who get all methods, you understand ?

Comment: Hi, sorry because I'm don't have that much of experience with PHP.
please see here http://prntscr.com/hx79zl
there is 3 of p_method_<?php echo $_code ?> which one should I add the code after?

Comment: Your welcome, if all is fine thanks to accept the answer